# UV Mapping exporting problem

Tags: uv, vector-mapping

i m making a body spray in blender & UV mapping it with my own design of JEPG formate . but when i try to export it for KEY SHOT or another software, only can model export but UV mapped image is not exporting, please help me

Comment: You have to save the image file separately in the UV Image editor.

Comment: Please describe little more , how to do this ?

Comment: Is your question actually how to export a textured model properly and import it in keyshot?

Comment: yes dear ......

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7YMh.png

Comment: its not working , actually i m new user . please help me out . my whats app number is . +971 52 7833582